# Not able to get the exact URL of the file on server located in active wordpress theme

Tags: php, theme-development

I am working on wordpress file, and I am having trouble with displaying total download count.

"Download count" is a number that I have saved in a text file "count.txt" located on server inside the active theme file.

Now in order to display the count, I am using the below code.

```
<?php 
$url= echo get_the_title();

echo file_get_contents( "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/download/$url/count.txt" ); 
//the URL of the text file consist of current wordpress post title. 
?>
```

Comment: Your question has no relation to WordPress. And don't  reinvent the wheel, use plugins like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-monitor/ to count downloads. Also you can find another such plugins by keywords "download monitor", "download counter" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a php var, for example `$url`, in a string in this manner:

```
file_get_contents( "http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/download/$url/count.txt" );
```

You can use [get_template_directory_uri](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to return the url to the current theme directory. For example:

```
$url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/download/count.txt';
echo file_get_contents( $url );
```